# How can I get a compiled directive to watch a variable from where it was compiled?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got a directive `testDirective` that's during run-time compiles another directive `testChart`. In `testDirective` I will have a variable that will be updated in this example its `scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5];`. During first run the directive `testChart` will recognize the `$scope.list` of its starting values but when `$scope.list`gets updated in the `setInterval`. The watch inside the `testChart` doesn't compile. Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<test-directive>
</test-directive>

<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("testDirective", ["$compile", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

          scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5];

          setInterval(function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < scope.list.length; i++) {
              scope.list[i] = scope.list[i] * 2;
            }
          }, 10000);         

          let content = angular.element('<test-chart></test-chart>');
          element.append(content);
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
}]);

app.directive('testChart', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                controllerAs: 'chartCtrl',
                template: '<div><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
                controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$compile', function ChartController($scope, $element, $attrs, $compile) {
                    //var html = $element.html();
                    $scope.$watch('list', function () {
                        console.log($scope.list);
                    });                    

                    $scope.chartId = $scope.$id;
                    //$element.html(html);
                    let content = angular.element('<div><div id="container'+ $scope.chartId + '"></div></div>');
                    $element.append(content);
                    var html = $element.html();
                    var hc = Highcharts.chart('container' + $scope.chartId, {

                    });
                }]
            };
        })      
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIW7BMREF7L2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is issue in $watch.

If you need to apply watch in array or object angular have third parameter in $watch please check angular document.

as per your issue, it will be resolve after apply below changes.

```
$scope.$watch('list', function () {
                    console.log($scope.list);
                },true);
```

and yes you also need to add $interval as per Tjaart van der Walt answer because setInterval javascript api so if you going to use this core api then you need to apply angular digest cycle so better is you going to use $interval angular api.

Comment: Right answer was a combination of your answer and Tjaart van der Walt

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead of `setInterval` to notify angular of the changes you made to the object.

```
app.directive("testDirective", ["$compile", "$interval" function($compile, $interval) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

      $interval(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.list.length; i++) {
          scope.list[i] = scope.list[i] * 2;
        }
      }, 10000);         

      let content = angular.element('<test-chart></test-chart>');
      element.append(content);
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
}}]);
```